# How to use axon with spring cloud in a micro services system

Tags: axon

I have a micro services system, 5 or 6 services. And I want to modify it with event sourcing architect on Axon.

I saw the part of distributed command bus and event but in the doc, but I still don't understand very well. Can anyone tell me the big picture about implementing axon in spring cloud system. Like how to configure command bus, event bus, MQ, and how to config datasource. How the event stores in micro service, and how the aggregate object generated from that.

Or, is there any example project for that? I found 2 in github, but it is too old.

Thanks.

Comment: That's definitely not a short answer you're looking for here. Maybe this (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IhLSwCRyrcw) YouTube vid. by Allard might give you some of the needed insights.
If that's not sufficient, please send some follow up questions.

Comment: Actually I have watched this. Maybe I need to watch again. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for no coming up with something more concrete. Chopping up the question in smaller portions might proof beneficial to getting answers quickly. 
Additionally, reaching out on the AxonFramework Google Usergroup might work. As it stands there are (sadly) more people active there then here on StackOverflow.